# Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.IActionSelectorDecisionTreeProvider'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, odata

I'm attempting to build the [AutoOdataEF](https://github.com/afgbeveridge/AutoODataEF.Core) project with little success.

I'm getting the following exception:

> Generated.OData.EF.API> Application startup exception:
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.IActionSelectorDecisionTreeProvider'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>   Generated.OData.EF.API>    at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void*
>   pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle,
>   IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
>   Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   System.Signature..ctor(IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType
>   declaringType) Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParametersNoCopy()
>   Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParameters()
>   Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Type
>   serviceType, Type implementationType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
>   Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor
>   descriptor, Type serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
>   Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type
>   serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain) Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type
>   serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain) Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type
>   serviceType, Type implementationType, ISet`1 callSiteChain,
>   ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
>   Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Type
>   serviceType, Type implementationType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
>   Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor
>   descriptor, Type serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
>   Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type
>   serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain) Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type
>   serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain) Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider) Generated.OData.EF.API> 
>   at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue,TArg](ConcurrentDictionary`2
>   dictionary, TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg arg)
>   Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
>   serviceType) Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType) Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider) Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseMvc(IApplicationBuilder
>   app, Action`1 configureRoutes) Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Autogenerated.OData.Api.ODataEfApiGeneratorExtensions.UseODataEFGenerator(IApplicationBuilder
>   app) Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Generated.OData.EF.API.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
>   IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
>   Generated.OData.EF.API> --- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown --- Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder
>   app) Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsightsStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   app) Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   app) Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder
>   builder) Generated.OData.EF.API>    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
>   Generated.OData.EF.API> crit:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.Web

I'm able to successfully go through these steps:

> Clone the repo/Download a zip Open the OData-EF-APIGenerator solution
>   Restore packages as necessary Build the solution Open the nuget
>   package manager console, ensure the default project is set to
>   EF.Example, and execute Update-Database, which will build and seed an
>   initial SQL Express database. If you have SQL server instead of SQL
>   express, just modify the connection strings in the EF.Example project

I fail on the last step:

```
Press F5, which should start the Generated.OData.EF.API project
```

[image]

**What am doing wrong? How do I get this to build?**

I've zipped the entire solution [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B47fuJY78GQhUkt4YlZWQUczWDQ/view?usp=sharing), including packages.