# Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.IActionSelectorDecisionTreeProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, odata

I'm developing an OData ASP Net Core API. This is the part of the code that i have troubles:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //Adding Model class to OData
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<CustomEntity>(nameof(CustomEntity));
        //Enabling OData routing.
        app.UseMvc(routebuilder =>
        {
            routebuilder.MapODataRoute("odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
        });

        //app.UseMvc();
    }
```

In `app.UseMvC` line i got this error:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.IActionSelectorDecisionTreeProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Is there a solution for this? I read that this type is no longer Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.2. Is there a way to introduce the type such that the VS 2017 can take it from other file and not the assembly?
This question is related: [Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.IActionSelectorDecisionTreeProvider'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117251/could-not-load-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-internal-iactionselectordecisiontr/48448551?noredirect=1#comment83889499_48448551)

Comment: I usually see this error if I use DotNetStandard in a project that is referenced into another one, but I don't reference DotNetStandard nuget for both

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old Question, but I just had a similar issue. I was able to fix it by deleting the project reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core`.

The specific module I had problems with is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.IPropertyInfoParameterDescriptor`, but it was the same type of error: "Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.XXXXXX' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core ....".

I found someone with the same error type with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionConstraintCache` and the solution that worked for me was to delete that reference. As the solution says, the reference isn't necessary and it turns out to be an incompatible version.

> jkotas commented on Sep 25, 2019:
> Try deleting <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" /> from your app .csproj. The ASP.NET projects get this reference by default in .NET Core 3.0. Explicitly referencing 2.2.5 in your .csproj is downgrading this package to 2.2 version that is not compatible with 3.0.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13478

I'm hoping this helps others in the future, since it's likely too late to help the OP.